# Will installation from source in different conda env lead to conflict?

Tags: anaconda, pytorch, conda

I want to install a nightly-version(v1.2) of pytorch from source in a new conda env, and I got v1.1 outside conda env installed from pip.

Will that lead to conflict?

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't change anything else about your environment, then not. Conda shields its environment from the host environment in the sense that it comes with its own python distribution, libraries etc., hence there should be no conflicts.

Note, however, that conda also comes with `pip`, so you need to make sure that the `pip` you used to install `v1.1` is indeed your host's `pip` and not conda's own `pip`.

Comment: Do you mean that all the conda envs share the same `pip`? And my first pip install is conda pip, how should I deal the v1.2 installation from source ?

Comment: @inkzk Nope, your system (I guess some kind of linux) probably also has a `pip`. Type `which pip` in the terminal and you'll know which pip you are using. Each conda env has its _own_ `pip`, so what I would do is to have one environment for v1.2 and one for v1.1. In each of the environment, you can use `pip` to install it.